# Credible Space-Exploration Sources

Tags: discussion

I'm unaware of a comprehensive list of websites that produce space-related news of-which are accepted, credible sources for this SE. Can we get a "thread" of websites, which are, in your personal opinion, credible? Over-time the ones that are opinionated but bad will be downvoted, and the best will be upvoted. I don't mind you listing multiple credible sources of information per post, but please try to quantify them in some way. Even if the source seems obvious, you're welcome to list it, having a fully-qualified list for international space-sources would be great!

***I feel like this will help new-comers get more interested in the SE and provide better sources than QUORA and ilk of that manner.***

---

**Example Source:**

[NASA Jet Propulsion Laboratory](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/)

- Credible news source directly from the people who took us to the moon!
- Additional resources linking to possible credible articles or interesting and relevant information.

---

**Suggested Format:**

```
[Title of News Source 1](Link to News Source 1)

  - Information about the News Source 1.
  - Information about the News Source 1.
  - Etc...
```

Comment: Also, it is important not to too quickly discredit sites like [Quora](https://www.quora.com/profile/Robert-Frost-1) and [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/BuzzAldrinHere).

Comment: I agree; IMHO it's better to have a known-unreliable answer than none at all (so you have a general hint, a non-authoritative answer that can be improved further). Also obviously questions referencing completely unreliable sources are completely fine; we're here to verify them!

Comment: I wonder if there is a tidy way to sub-classify spaceflight/industry news (e.g. Company X's communications satellite constellation, Iodine-based thrusters, Scottish launch pads...) versus space science news (e.g. rotten eggs on Uranus, asteroid from another solar system,) versus Space Agency news (e.g. NASA's indecisiveness between Moon and Mars, ISRO manned missions one step closer to reality)? Or perhaps would the boundaries not be so clear?

Comment: @uhoh common sense is often a resource found later-- sometimes, anyway. People need time to learn boundaries like me. What is and what isnt takes a long time. So many countlesss conspiracy theories Ive seen without credibility... I dont think we need a sqaud to say YOURE WRONG... But to vilify accurate information from its source.

Comment: I was just suggesting some sub-categories for the forthcoming "listification".

Answer (score 3):

### News

[AzerNews](https://www.azernews.az/)

- Center-right, pro-establishment Azerbaijani news source (English language)
- Contains space news for Central Asia and the Middle East
- Often has a bias, but may contain more details than available elsewhere at times

[CNN Light Years](http://lightyears.blogs.cnn.com/)

- Mixed reliability space and science news source
- US mainstream media

[Gizmodo Space](https://gizmodo.com/tag/space)

- Moderately reliable space news source
- As a tech news site, often has a more tech-focused perspective of space

[Instituto Nacional de Pesquisas Espaciais (INPE)](http://www.inpe.br/)

- Brazil's National Institute for Space Research (official website)
- Excellent source of Brazilian space news and resources

[NASA Langley Research Center](https://www.nasa.gov/langley)

- Official website of the NASA center devoted to aeronautics and space research
- Excellent source of NASA news and resources

[NASA Science](https://science.nasa.gov/)

- Science news with direct oversight by NASA scientists
- Excellent source for space news

[Popular Mechanics](https://www.popularmechanics.com/)

- Very reliable science and technology news source
- Often contains articles on space exploration

[Popular Science](https://www.popsci.com/)

- Very reliable science news source
- Often contains articles on space exploration

[Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/)

- Very reliable science news source
- Has a collection of over 7000 articles on space going back to 1845
- Authors include [Albert Einstein](https://www.scientificamerican.com/magazine/sa/1950/04-01/#article-on-the-generalized-theory-of-gravit)

[Space.com](https://www.space.com/)

- Very reliable space news source
- Stays up-to-date on space exploration and astronomy
- Often has good video resources and interviews

[U.S. Air Force News](https://www.af.mil/News/)

- Official website of the U.S. Air Force
- Contains a Space/Technology news category

### Technical

[MIT's Space Propulsion Laboratory](http://spl.mit.edu/)

- Official website of MIT's experimental propulsion laboratory
- Contains technical information and references to scientific literature

[Stanford Einstein](http://einstein.stanford.edu/)

- Stanford's website related to their efforts to test Einstein's theories
- Official website of Gravity Probe B (also contains details on Gravity Probe A)
- Lots of articles and resources at varying levels of specialization

### Other official documents

[JSC History](https://www.jsc.nasa.gov/history/)

- Resources on the history of US space exploration provided by NASA's Johnson Space Center (JSC)
- Contains mission details and transcripts for Mercury, Gemini, and Apollo
- Note: Links to `http://www-pao.ksc.nasa.gov/history/` are out of date. Refer to https://science.ksc.nasa.gov/history/ instead.

[NASA History Program Office](https://history.nasa.gov/)

- Central repository for NASA history

[NASA Office of Inspector General](https://oig.nasa.gov/)

- Official website of the NASA OIG
- Contains official documents and news related to auditing, investigation, counsel, and management of NASA

### Scholarly publications

[PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/)

- National Center for Biotechnology Information (NCBI)'s official repository of biomedical literature
- Useful for searches of biomedical-related space science literature
- *Very useful* source, more than you might think is "biomedical-related" (e.g. [The resources of Mars for human settlement - Meyer TR, McKay CP](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11539074))

### Other

[Beyond Belief: Skepticism, Science and the Paranormal](https://books.google.com/books?id=jV_63sZBUg8C&dq)

- Expensive (about 37 USD) ebook from Cambridge University Press
- Contains a chapter on UFO sightings, including details about sightings by astronauts

[Deke!](https://books.google.com/books?id=_S-PoBi8Eu8C&dq)

- Cheap (about 8 USD) ebook autobiography of astronaut Donald K. "Deke" Slayton
- Information on the days of Mercury, Gemini, Apollo, and Skylab from the first chief of American Astronaut Corps

[National Space Society](http://space.nss.org/)

- Official website of the non-profit organization dedicated to creating a space-faring civilization
- Various space resources, including articles and position papers

[Strategic Air Command & Aerospace Museum](https://sacmuseum.org/)

- Official website for the Smithsonian-affiliated non-profit museum
- Not a very information dense source, but has brief details on aircraft and spacecraft

[The Planets](https://theplanets.org/)

- Free to use and copy (Creative Commons) resource
- Lots of information on the solar system and other aspects of space
- Made to be easy to use by anyone: school age children and adults
- Images from NASA and a 3D solar system model

Comment: Here's some sources from my questions to get us started. I'll add sources from my answers later. Sources are ordered alphabetically under each category heading.